# Rewrite/Prettify search urls on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to prettify the search URL on my Wordpress blog like follow :

> someblog.com/?s=some_query ==> someblog.com/search/some_query

=>This works fine :)

> someblog.com/?s=some_query&post_type=myview ==> someblog.com/search/myview/some_query

=>Not working right now, the search is made using this "myview/some_query".

How can I do it ? Preferably only by modifying my .htaccess, any other solution including some php code is welcome as well ;)

Snippet form my .htaccess :

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/\?s=([^\s]+)\&post_type=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search/%2/%1? [L,R,NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/\?s=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ search/%1? [L,R,NC]
```

BR.